# How to show programmatically the NSTextView's Find Panel?

Tags: swift, textview

How to show programmatically with Swift 3 the NSTextView's Find Panel in macOS?

The only info I found is to set and get its properties and some others but not how to show and hide it (for example):

> **var usesFindBar: Bool**
>   A Boolean value that indicates whether to use the find bar for this text view.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstextview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [performFindPanelAction()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstextview/1449525-performfindpanelaction), with [.showFindInterface](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstextfinderaction/1534562-showfindinterface).  ([.showFindPanel](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsfindpanelaction/1449157-showfindpanel) works, too, but is deprecated.)

Note that you can't pass the action directly.  You'll need something with a `var tag: Int` that can hold it:

```
button.tag = NSTextFinder.Action.showFindInterface.rawValue
textview.performFindPanelAction(button)
```